# how to move other elements when accordion is checked?

Tags: html, css, accordion

I have a situation i couldn't solve myself with standard CSS and html.
I made a flexbox section and added two accordion panels with the text inside.

### problem

It works as planned, but whenever I open my accordion (checkbox:checked) the window with the text goes over the other element.
[image]

### How it should work

Once my accordion is opened, I want it to increase the height (or with other method) of element1 as shown on the image below, so it wouldn't overflow the second element below. Basically, if the checkbox is checked, it should move other elements without showing it on top of each other. Is it possible to fix this problem with standard tools?

```css
.career {
    background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #d1d1d3);
}

.career h2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: purple;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

.accord-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 40px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 100px;
    margin-top: -50px;
}

.accord {
    width: 500px;
    height: 60px;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #82e6ff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 10px;
    background: linear-gradient(#6960b9, #453f7a);
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
}

.accord-label, .accord-text {
    padding: 14px 20px;
}

.accord-label {
    display: block;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    transition: background 0.2s;
}

.accord-label:hover {
    background: #3e3a5a;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.accord-label::after {
    content: " ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    right: 20px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-image: url(../images/arrow-accord.png);
    background-size: contain;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.accord-text {
    background: #ececec;
    line-height: 2.1;
    display: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.accord p {
    font-size: 20px;
}

.accord-input:checked ~ .accord-text {
    display: block;
}

.accord-input {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
    <section class="career">
        <h2>Education & Experience</h2>
        <div class="accord-container">
            <div class="accord">
                <input type="checkbox" name="careers-accordion" id="section1"class="accord-input">
                <label for="section1" class="accord-label">Education</label>
                <div class="accord-text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="accord"> 
                <input type="checkbox" name="careers-accordion" id="section2"class="accord-input">
                <label for="section2" class="accord-label">Career</label>
                <div class="accord-text">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

#### P.S.

I'm still learning CSS and I haven't touched bootstrap or JS yet

Comment: All you have to do is remove the set height on **.accord** so where you have `height: 60px;` just remove that line

Comment: @Simp4Code Thank you so much! it helped! Also, any suggestions on how to make it smooth when it is checked? It looks really raw once I open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments on your questions. You need to remove the height from **.accordion** -- and to animate it, with just CSS is a bit difficult, I've implemented a basic example that will expand from zero height but it appears a little jumpy when lines begin to wrap as the content grows. You can fiddle around with the active state using padding and so on maybe you can find something you like, but a proper smooth animation from height 0 to height auto will require a bit of JavaScript

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box } body { font: 16px sans-serif; margin: 0 }

.career {
  background: linear-gradient(#ffffff, #d1d1d3);
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  padding: 2rem;
}

.career h2 {
  color: #6960b9;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.accord-container {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.accord {
  background: linear-gradient(#6960b9, #453f7a);
  border-radius: .75rem;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #82e6ff;
  flex: 1 0 0%;
  min-width: 15rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.accord-input { display: none }

.accord-label {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  position: relative;
  text-indent: 1.5em;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.accord-label:hover { background: #3e3a5a }

.accord-label::after {
  content: "↓";
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: .5em;
  text-indent: 0;
  width: 1em;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.accord-text {
  background: #ececec;
  font-size: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  transition: font-size .5s .25s, padding .5s .25s, transform .5s;
}

.accord-input:checked~.accord-label { border-radius: .75rem .75rem 0 0 }
.accord-input:checked~.accord-label::after { transform: rotate(-180deg) }
.accord-input:checked~.accord-text {
  font-size: 1rem;
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  transform: translateX(0);
  transition: font-size .5s, padding .5s, transform .5s .25s;
}
```

```html
<section class="career">
  <h2>Education & Experience</h2>
  <div class="accord-container">
    <div class="accord">
      <input type="checkbox" name="careers-accordion" id="section1" class="accord-input">
      <label for="section1" class="accord-label">Education</label>
      <div class="accord-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="accord">
      <input type="checkbox" name="careers-accordion" id="section2" class="accord-input">
      <label for="section2" class="accord-label">Career</label>
      <div class="accord-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'll try to implement this for my project. But after i removed the height line i encountered a new problem. When i open for example the first accordion, the second (unchecked) accordion stretches to the first accordion window. 
Is there an easy solution to make first/second accord unaffected IF it is checked? 
Everything looks good if both accordions are opened, but a single opened accordion ruins the design

Comment: @Nibelur easy fix by adding `align-items: flex-start` to **.accord-container**

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'd never come to this solution myself 